# Обновление ColumnModel в JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

Как корректно обновить структуру столбцов в `JXTreeTable`? Имеется модель:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.AbstractTreeTableModel;

import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class NoRootTreeTableModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel{

    public String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Id", "Name", "Doj", "Photo"};

    private List<Department> departmentList;

    public NoRootTreeTableModel(List<Department> departmentList) {
        super(new Object());
        this.departmentList = departmentList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(Object node, int column) {
        if (node instanceof Department && column == 2) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return node instanceof Employee;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if (parent instanceof Department) {
            Department dept = (Department) parent;
            return dept.getEmployeeList().size();
        }
        return departmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if (parent instanceof Department) {
            Department dept = (Department) parent;
            return dept.getEmployeeList().get(index);
        }
        return departmentList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        Department dept = (Department) parent;
        Employee emp = (Employee) child;
        return dept.getEmployeeList().indexOf(emp);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(Object node, int column) {
        if (node instanceof Department) {
            Department dept = (Department) node;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return dept.getId();
                case 1:
                    return dept.getName();
                case 2:
                    return "case 2";
                case 3:
                    return "case 3";
            }
        } else if (node instanceof Employee) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) node;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return emp.getId();
                case 1:
                    return emp.getName();
                case 2:
                    return emp.getDoj();
                case 3:
                    return "case 3";
                case 4:
                    return "case 4";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, Object node, int column) {
        String strValue = (String) value;
        if (node instanceof Department) {
            Department dept = (Department) node;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    dept.setId(Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    dept.setName(strValue);
                    break;
            }
        } else if (node instanceof Employee) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) node;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    emp.setId(Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    emp.setName(strValue);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void newColumns() {
        String[] tmpArray = new String[COLUMN_NAMES.length + 1];

        System.arraycopy(COLUMN_NAMES, 0, tmpArray, 0, COLUMN_NAMES.length);
        tmpArray[tmpArray.length - 1] = "newColumn" + tmpArray.length;

        COLUMN_NAMES = tmpArray;

        this.modelSupport.fireTreeStructureChanged(new TreePath(root));

    }

    public void showColumnNames(){
        for (String s : COLUMN_NAMES){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `newColumn()` - добавляет столбец и вызывает обновление `JXTreeTable`.

main:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable;

public class TreeTableMain extends JFrame
{

    private JXTreeTable treeTable;

    private NoRootTreeTableModel noRootTreeTableModel;

    public TreeTableMain() 
    {
        final Date doj = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        List<Department> departmentList = new ArrayList<Department>();

        List<Employee> empList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList1.add(new Employee(1, "Kiran", doj, "emp1.jpg"));
        empList1.add(new Employee(2, "Prabhu", doj, "emp2.jpg"));
        empList1.add(new Employee(3, "Murugavel", doj, "emp1.jpg"));        
        departmentList.add(new Department(1, "Sales", empList1));

        List<Employee> empList2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList2.add(new Employee(4, "Deiveegan", doj, "emp2.jpg"));
        empList2.add(new Employee(5, "Saravanan", doj, "emp1.jpg"));
        departmentList.add(new Department(2, "Production", empList2));

        noRootTreeTableModel = new NoRootTreeTableModel(departmentList);
        treeTable = new JXTreeTable(noRootTreeTableModel);
        treeTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        treeTable.setRootVisible(false);
        treeTable.setRowHeight(50);
        add(new JScrollPane(treeTable));

        setTitle("JXTreeTable Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TreeTableMain t = new TreeTableMain();
                t.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Перед добавлением: " + t.treeTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount());
                        System.out.println("Перед добавлением: " + t.noRootTreeTableModel.getColumnCount());

                        t.noRootTreeTableModel.newColumns();

                        System.out.println("После добавления: " + t.treeTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount());
                        System.out.println("После добавления: " + t.noRootTreeTableModel.getColumnCount());
                        t.noRootTreeTableModel.showColumnNames();

                        //try to set width
                        //t.treeTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);    //error
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Визуально все работает (в `JXTreeTable` добавляется столбец), однако при попытки поменять ширину (`preferredWidth`), столбца выбрасывается исключение выхода за пределы массива.

Из вывода в консоль видно, что `ColumnModel` и `TreeTableModel` имеют разное количество столбцов. Причем вывод из `ColumnModel` показывает корректное значение только при следующем добавлении столбца.

Вывод в консоль:

```
Первая итерация:

    Перед добавлением: 4
    Перед добавлением: 4
    После добавления: 4
    После добавления: 5
    Id
    Name
    Doj
    Photo
    newColumn5

Вторая итерация:

    Перед добавлением: 5
    Перед добавлением: 5
    После добавления: 5
    После добавления: 6
    Id
    Name
    Doj
    Photo
    newColumn5
    newColumn6
```

Как видно только со 2 итерации в `ColumnModel` появился 5 столбец. Собственно основной вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении (вызов метода `modelSupport.fireTreeStructureChanged(new TreePath(root))`) сразу обновлялась `ColumnModel`?